# Is the phrase "Coming of days" reserved for specific people?

Tags: hebrew, melachim-kings-book-of, joshua--book-of, parashat-chaye-sara

I searched the phrase באים בימים (and related grammatical instances, such as בא בימים, etc.). It seems to occur regarding only these people:

- Avraham and Sarah - Breishit 18:11
- Avraham alone - Breishit 24:1
- Yehoshua (Joshua) as mentioned in Joshua 13:1, 23:1, and 23:2
- David (Samuel) - Melachim I (Kings I) 1:1

The phrase means literally, "coming of days". One explanation that I have heard about this phrase is that it means that these people made each day of their life "count" and each day they did something significant.

This is a nice explanation, but, I think this can be said about other notable people in Tanac"h. I would think that this could be said about Moshe and Aharon, among others. But, you don't see this phrase used for them.

Is there something special about this phrase that it is said about only the people I mentioned in the list?

Comment: My Rebbe has an interesting pshat in what it means, but it doesn’t answer your question (if anything, it makes it stronger). Maybe you could add in how you understand the phrase?

Comment: Also, I added in tags corresponding to the pesukim cited. As always, if you disagree there’s a rollback button for a reason.

Comment: @DonielF I appreciate the tagging. I'm not sure if it's on target, for this type of question, but, I couldn't think of other appropriate tags. I don't really understand the phrase any better than that explanation that I heard. All it seems to mean to me otherwise is that it's synonymous with saying "about to die". But, it seems that the phrase is together with the word *zaken*. (I have to verify that this is true with all the above cases.) If so, I wonder what this phrase adds that the word *zaken* isn't conveying.

Comment: It clearly doesn’t mean “about to die” since it was used by Avraham when he was 99, and later at 140, although he died at 175. Sarah also got the label at 89 yet lived almost another 40 years (until 127). That pshat I mentioned earlier - my Rebbe says that “zakein” means getting older, while “ba bayamim” means getting better with age (taking his days, rather than wasting them).

Comment: @DonielF Good point made in your 1st sentence!